# python: checking if a number is prime, specifying range

Tags: python, range

I have a problem with a this piece of code that I'm writing to check if a number is prime.

```
import sys
import math 

def is_prime(num):
    for j in range(2,(int(math.sqrt(num)+1))):
        if (num % j) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

for a in range(1,10):
    if is_prime(a):
        print a
```

What I get is: 5, 7, 9

I don't understand why is 3 excluded? I went back to the first portion of the code and tried `is_prime(3)`, but it returned me neither True nor False. Does this mean that 3 is outside the range of divisors I'm checking? How should I correct the code such that 3 is included in my list of primes?

Edit:
Hello again, thanks for the answers so far, so I've tried to solve the problem of truncation using int(round()). I've also tried putting the `else` block outside the loop, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please explain why this is insufficient and suggest how I should correct it so it works? Thanks in advance! :)

```
import sys
import math 

def is_prime(num):
    for j in range(2,int(round(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
        if (num % j) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: for a in range(1,10):
    print is_prime(a)

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns `True` as soon as it sees that the number is not divisible by *any* `j`. It should only return `True` if the number is not divisible by *all* `j`.

As a side-effect of fixing this bug, you'll also fix the bug whereby your function sometimes returns `None` (for example, when `num` is `3`).

Answer (score 1):

`int()` truncates, not rounds, so `int(math.sqrt(3) + 1) == 2`. `range(2, 2)` is empty, so nothing will be returned.

Another problem is that your `else` block is *inside* of the loop. If you test the first 100 numbers, you will quickly notice that your `is_prime` function will return `True` for any odd number.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of 3 is less than 2, so the loop is never entered and nothing is returned.